# jquery-mobile: turn off theming for desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm using jquery-mobile for a Google Apps Script that I want to load as a web app but also as a dialog/sidebar in Sheets. In the script I use jquery-mobile's grid support, so I require its css & js. However, I don't want it's theming when on the desktop. Is there a way to turn it off if the device is not mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control jQuery Mobile's framework *auto initializing*. On `mobileinit` event - which fires before `.ready()` - check if user agent is a desktop or tablet/mobile. If it's a desktop browser, stop jQuery Mobile from *auto initializing* the framework.

The code below should be placed in `head` after jQuery.js (core) and before jQuery-Mobile.js

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function (e, data) {
    if ( isDesktop() ) { /* isDesktop() is your custom function to check user agent */
        $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    }
});
```

Now, your website isn't controlled by jQuery Mobile, however, you still can use *grid* system as it is only classes and there is no JavaScript code involved.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap up everything inside a form and set the property `data-role` to none, for the form.
Refer to the documentation [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html)

It's a bit old though. But, I guess same should work.

Comment: i want to use part of the css (grid support, pages), but just not the themes

Comment: Well, in that case, you can set the data-enhance=”false” on different sections like header, footer and all. If you apply it to an element, all the children of it wont be applied with the styling.

Comment: sorry, didn't work for me. I even used  $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled